# adding shipping calculator to woocommerce order page

Tags: woocommerce

In Woocommerce on the "edit order" page, is there any way to display all of the shipping methods and their costs for that order? A bit like the shipping calculator the customer sees on the cart page or checkout page, but on the edit order page instead?

Or alternatively, to add all of the items and customer shipping postcode etc from the order back to a new cart session so we can see the shipping caclulator in the cart page using this data?

extracting the products from the order using something like:

```
$order_items = $order_object->get_items( array('line_item', 'fee', 'shipping') );
if ( !is_wp_error( $order_items ) ) {
foreach( $order_items as $item_id => $order_item ) {
    echo $order_item->get_quantity(); // or $order_item['quantity'];
    echo $order_item->get_product_id(); // or $order_item['product_id'];
    echo $order_item->get_variation_id(); // or $order_item['variation_id'];
    echo $order_item->get_product(); // get the associated product
}
}
```

And then wp_create_order() to add those to a new cart?

Many thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've updated the post. I think the desired behaviour is clear. I am unsure of the exact code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code, would this work with the modern version of woocommerce?

```
// Post variables
$order_id   = isset($_POST['order_id'])?$_POST['order_id']:0;
$country    = isset($_POST['country'])?$_POST['country']:0;
$state      = isset($_POST['state'])?$_POST['state']:0;
$postcode   = isset($_POST['postcode'])?$_POST['postcode']:0;
$city       = isset($_POST['city'])?$_POST['city']:0;

// Order and order items
$order          = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order_items    = $order->get_items();

// Reset shipping first
WC()->shipping()->reset_shipping();

// Set correct temporary location
if ( $country != '' ) {
WC()->customer->set_billing_location( $country, $state, $postcode, $city );
WC()->customer->set_shipping_location( $country, $state, $postcode, $city );
} else {
WC()->customer->set_billing_address_to_base();
WC()->customer->set_shipping_address_to_base();
}

// Remove all current items from cart
if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
WC()->cart->empty_cart();
}

// Add all items to cart
foreach ($order_items as $order_item) {
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($order_item['product_id'], $order_item['qty']);
}

// Calculate shipping
$packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
$shipping = WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping($packages);
$available_methods = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
```